# Pegar o maior valor por categoria carregando também o ID

Tags: sql, query, group-by

A tabela está no formato abaixo

```
ID | CATEGORIA | QUANTIDADE 
1  |   A       | 23
2  |   A       | 12
3  |   A       | 11
1  |   B       | 15 
2  |   B       | 10
```

Queria uma *query* que me retornasse a seguinte tabela

```
ID | CATEGORIA | QUANTIDADE 
1  |   A       | 23
1  |   B       | 15
```

Ou seja Id que possui a maior quantidade em cada categoria.

Obs: Não pode ser usado `partition by`

Comment: Tu tens dois *ids* iguais na mesma tabela? Aliás, qual banco é?

Comment: Da uma verificada na minha resposta, deve funcionar.

Comment: Conseguiu a query que queria ? aceito uma resposta como correta

Answer (score 6):

Olá,

Veja um exemplo abaixo..

```
declare @tabela table
(
     ID int,
     Categora char(1),
     quantidade int
)

insert into @tabela 
values 
(1  ,   'A'       , 23),
(2  ,   'A '      , 12),
(3  ,   'A'       , 11),
(1  ,   'B'       , 15 ),
(2  ,   'B'       , 10)


select P.* from
(
    select Categora, MAX(quantidade) as quantidade from @tabela
    group by Categora
) D
join @tabela P
on P.Categora = D.Categora
and P.quantidade = D.quantidade
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4):

Você tem id e categoria iguais, portanto é uma chave primária composta, pode trazer o que procura com uma subquery no HAVING, assim vai funcionar:

```
SELECT id, categoria, quantidade
FROM categoria cat
GROUP BY id, categoria, quantidade
HAVING quantidade = (SELECT MAX(quantidade) FROM categoria WHERE categoria = cat.categoria)
ORDER BY categoria, id
```

Outra forma é com uma window function:

```
SELECT id, categoria, quantidade
FROM (
    SELECT id,
            categoria,
            quantidade,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY categoria ORDER BY quantidade DESC ) AS rank
    FROM categoria cat
) AS categoria_ranqueada
WHERE categoria_ranqueada.rank = 1
ORDER BY categoria, id
```

Qualquer problema é só informar.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode fazer um subselect para isso.

```
SELECT a.ID, a.CATEGORIA, (SELECT max(b.QUANTIDADE) 
FROM TABELA b WHERE b.CATEGORIA = a.CATEGORIA) AS QUANTIDADE 
FROM TABELA a GROUP BY a.CATEGORIA;
```

Considere um ID único para cada linha da tabela, ou uma chave composta com o ID e a CATEGORIA, porque observando pela estrutura que você forneceu levando em consideração somente o ID existe uma violação de chave primária.

Comment: Essa query não traz o ID certo

Comment: Editei a resposta levando em consideração isso, não se sabe se é composta inclusive.

Comment: Não por isso. Levando em consideração que o ID seja chave única, essa query não trará os ids corretamente.

Comment: SELECT D.FILM_ID, TITLE,RATING, ALUGADO
 FROM(SELECT  B.FILM_ID, COUNT(*) ALUGADO
 FROM RENTAL A, INVENTORY B 
 WHERE A.INVENTORY_ID = B.INVENTORY_ID
 GROUP BY B.FILM_ID
 ORDER BY B.FILM_ID) D, FILM E
 WHERE D.FILM_ID = E.FILM_ID

Comment: Essa é a query original que daria origem a essa tabela que coloquei com exemplo, não sei se ajuda muito, maaaas ta ai. o nome do banco de dados é Pagila, acho que é bem conhecido. É o bd de uma locadora

Comment: E somente o campo ID é chave primária?

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT CATEGORIA.ID, MAX(CATEGORIA.QUANTIDADE) AS QUANTIDADE
FROM CATEGORIA
GROUP BY CATEGORIA.CATEGORIA
```

Ahh, uma dica, `SEMPRE` utilize em suas consultas, o nome completo, desta maneira `TABELA.CAMPO`.

Você não faz ideia de quanto isso melhora a leitura(de humanos) da sua consulta.

Seus colegas serão muito gratos.

Também deixei um exemplo aqui, qualquer duvida, só pedir.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7c9d3/2

Comment: Se for uma tabela com um nome muito grande também pode ser usado uma abreviação... Exe: FROM CATEGORIA as Cat

Comment: @Ilario Junior GROUP BY CATEGORIA.CATEGORIA, isso funciona ?

Comment: @TiagoOliveiradeFreitas Isso deve ter sido apenas um engano. Pois na _query_ o `group by` deve referenciar ao campo de agrupamento presente na _query_.

Comment: Buenas!
Não, não foi por engano.
Isso funciona sim, ao menos nos bancos com quais trabalho (Firebird e SQL Server).

Quando tenho uma das colunas(ou mais) filtrando pela maior, ou menor, ou até mesmo dando um count(*), precisa-se agrupar a query pelas demais colunas.
Caso contrário, qual o sentido de estar buscando por um valor especifico na tupla se os demais dados não estão de acordo ?