# Selecionar maior valor da data mais recente

Tags: sql

Possuo uma tabela `estoque` onde ficam armazenados os registros de todos os suprimentos, com a **data de entrada no estoque**, o **código do suprimento** e o **valor unitário** da peça, minha necessidade seria pegar o maior valor unitário da data mais recente de cada suprimento:

```
Data     | Suprimento | Valor
08/02/18 |      A     | 150,00
08/02/18 |      A     | 255,00  
06/02/18 |      A     | 300,00
02/02/18 |      B     | 100,00
```

Retorno:

```
Data     | Suprimento | Valor
08/02/18 |      A     | 255,00  
02/02/18 |      B     | 100,00
```

Ou seja quero selecionar o item de maior valor da data mais recente, me preocupando em pegar a maior data e o maior valor dentro dessa data, diferente do exemplo citado que se preocupa somente em pegar o de maior quantidade.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Pegar o maior valor por categoria carregando também o ID](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/93805/pegar-o-maior-valor-por-categoria-carregando-tamb%c3%a9m-o-id)

Answer (score 1):

Você pode buscar pelo maior valor usando `MAX(Valor)` e utilizar claúsula `HAVING` em conjunto com uma `subquery` para trazer somente os maiores valores das datas que forem iguais as maiores datas de cada suprimento:

```
SELECT 
  Suprimento
  , MAX(Valor)
  , Data
FROM Estoque
GROUP BY Suprimento, Data
HAVING Data = (
  SELECT MAX(Estoque1.Data) 
  FROM Estoque [Estoque1] 
  WHERE Estoque1.suprimento = Estoque.Suprimento
)
ORDER BY Suprimento
```

[SQLFiddle exemplo Online](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8a935/45)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    aux.*
FROM(
SELECT
    *
FROM estoque
ORDER BY `data` DESC, valor DESC) AS aux
GROUP BY `suprimento`;
```

Comment: Não entendi a sua `query`, poderia explicá-la?